# xpages triggering lotusscript code from SSJS

Tags: xpages

I've got a form that has a log number field.  The value of the log number is generated by a piece of LotusScript code.  I don't really want to rewrite it in javaScript if I can help it as it works fine.  So I did some digging and found a technique for firing LotusScript.  The idea is that in your SSJS code you create a document then pass the id of that document to an agent. You fire the agent.  The agent then runs the code, updates a field and then back in the SSJS code, you read the contents of the document updated by the agent.  The problem I'm having is that when I read back the updated doc, the fields read in the SSJS code are empty tho the document was created the fields updated as I needed them to.  I'm thinking it must be a timing thing.  I put the code in the OnClientLoad event of the xpage.  I can see the doc created, the LogNumber field filed in correctly but it's not visible to the SSJS code and I'm not sure why.

thanks
clem

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's difficult to help. Are you using Computed with form?

Comment: Please check the following Wiki: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=936D3C63F4F7A2A88525777A003CB325#mobileViewer

Answer (score 3):

If you update a backend document outside of the SSJS, I think you'll need to recycle the Document, then get it again afresh.

Personally, I'd recommend taking the time to convert it to SSJS. If you look at the recent webinar I did for TLCC with Mike McGarel, I did that live and there's a slide of some things to check for http://tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/recorded-xpages-webinars?opendocument.
It may take some time, but it will increase your confidence with SSJS and makes it easier for moving, at a later stage, to Java (which is what I do later in the webinar).

Comment: I second Paul. Write that function once in a SsJS lib and be done. Anything else will bite you

Comment: I suspected that would be the recommendation. ;-)  My javascript is not very strong at the moment but it looks like I'll be a javascript expert pretty soon!  Thanks.  I already started looking at some tutorials.  I appreciate the feedback.

Clem

Comment: Well, that wasn't too bad.  Found a couple youtube tutorials, rewrote the function to generate the logNumber in javascript.  Wasn't as bad as I thought it would be.  Thanks again!